# QDataStream allocation between members

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdatastream

```
class ReadFile {
  public:
    void init();
    QList<double> getData();
  private:
    QFile file;
    QDataStream read;
    double bufferFloat;
    quint32 bufferInteger
}
```

The idea is now that when init() is called, the a file should be opened and navigated into a location where the data starts. Now, every time getData() is called, a chunk of bytes should be read from the file.

Pseudo-code looks like this:

```
void ReadFile::init()
{
  file.setFileName("...");
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  QDataStream read(&file);

  // This chunk does some magic to find correct location by applying
  // a readout (read >> bufferInteger) and check the result

  // I can verify that at this point, if doing a readout (read >> bufferFloat)
  // I get good data (i.e. corresponding to the file).
}
```

and

```
QList<double> ReadFile::getData()
{
  // Doing a (read >> bufferFloat) at this point will result in zeros.
}
```

I understand why this happens, since the `read` in `init` is declared locally. But how should I allocate the data stream so `getData` can pick up where `init` left off? And the next `getData` can pick up where the previous left off. A call sequence would look like:

```
ReadFile file();
file.init();
file.readData();
file.readData();
file.readData();
file.readData();
//etc...
```

Comment: Make `QFile` a class member.

Comment: @Amartel Please take a look at the updated code. I put QFile file as a member, but this does not help the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your code. This line:

```
QDataStream read(&file);
```

defines a local variable, which overrides class member. Instead you should do this:

```
read.setDevice(&file);
```

Comment: This does it. I was looking for a .setFile method, did not realize QFile inherited from QIODevice. Thank you :-)